# How can I create dependant dropdowns in Excel based off related cells?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Trying to accomplish this without using VBA - I have two sets of data: Categories and SubCategories both which include a name/description as well as a number to identify them.  I have a dropdown using Data Validation for the categories which uses a VLOOKUP to pull in the corresponding number for that category.  I'm now trying to create a second drop down which will show me subcategories but only to their corresponding categories.  The list of categories and subcategories are listed on separate sheets.  The subcategory also has a 3rd column which lists the category number.  See below for an example.

```
SubCategory SubCatNumber    Category Number
Carrots     00              10
Celery      02              10
Onions      03              10
Apples      00              12
Bananas     02              12
Cantaloupe  03              12
```

So the drop down for the sub cats would show me Carrots, Celery and Onions when I choose Category 10 from my existing drop down.   I've tried using another VLOOKUP as well as a combination of INDEX and OFFSET but can't seem to get this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Link each of your dropdowns to a named range, so that whatever is in the cells of the named range will appear in the dropdowns.

Create ranges (to name them will be easier) for each of the subcategories and fill them with the correct choices.

Finally, link the range linked to the sub-category dropdown to the named range defined by the selection in the main category dropdown.

Here are two examples, both based on the named ranges shown in this picture [image: this picture.]

Example 1 requires a little code.
[image]

Example 2 works without code.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the reply and extensive example - however I don't think this will quite work for what I'm trying to do.  I'm not needing to select an item of Rice based on it being part of a category named Grains.  I need to be able to select Rice based on a category number that is associated with Grains.  I'm going to play around with named ranges though and see if I cna come up with anything that works.

Comment: Whether "Grains" is a number or a word shouldn't make any difference. The point is that every selection in the first dropdown leads to a list for the second. That list must either exist (Example 1) or it must be generated on the fly (Example 2).

Comment: The other thing I'm noticing with your example as well as others on the net is that my data needs to be in 3 columns - whereas yours is broken out in separate columns for each item (see my example in initial post). Any way I can generate a list in similar fashion with that constraint?

Comment: In my example, you have five categories (Fruit, Grains, Meats, Sweets, Vegetable) which are in a **horizontal** list. You would require only two, (10 and 12). Under the category 10 you would have Carrots, Celery, Onions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help on this.  Ultimately you were right and this was simply a matter of creating dynamic named ranges and then using the OFFSET function to be able to provide a drop down based on a vertically aligned list. This was the funciton I ended up using for my second level drop down

=OFFSET(CatStart,MATCH(D3,CatSubCatColumn,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(CatSubCatColumn,D3),1)